# Data analysis code (finds coincidences in three sets of data)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've written the following data analysis code (using just a couple lines from CERN's ROOT data analysis framework). It's designed to find coincidences in three sets of data (timestamps from an experiment for a given year) by pairing up each timestamp in one dataset with the closest possible timestamp in both the second and third datasets, then sorting those pairings by maxval - minval, and keeping only the closest "unique" coincidences (no two coincidences may share a timestamp, and each coincidence is a triplet, with one timestamp contributed by each dataset). The code works perfectly, however it's a bit messy and could probably use some cleaning up. Perhaps there are some clever tricks for simplifying some of this that I'm unaware of as well. Please do be very critical, I appreciate the feedback.

My code:

```
int binary_search(const vector<double> &vec, const double key) {

    int high = vec.size();
    int low  = 0; 
    unsigned int mid;

    while(low <= high){
        mid = low + (high-low)/2;

        if(vec[mid] == key) return mid;
        else if(vec[mid] < key)  low = mid + 1;
        else high = mid - 1;
    }

    return mid;

}

void binary(){
    
    ROOT::RDataFrame statn1("D", "./path/to/data");
    ROOT::RDataFrame statn2("D", "./path/to/data");
    ROOT::RDataFrame statn3("D", "./path/to/data");

    vector<double> vec2, vec3;
    statn2.Foreach([&](double tstamp){vec2.push_back(tstamp);},{"UNIX"});
    statn3.Foreach([&](double tstamp){vec3.push_back(tstamp);},{"UNIX"});
    
    vector<vector<double> > coincidences;
    statn1.Foreach([&](double tstamp){},
    
        int res_i = binary_search(vec2, tstamp);

        double p = dabs(tstamp-vec2[res_i]); 
        double q = dabs(tstamp-vec2[res_i+1]); 
        double r = dabs(tstamp-vec2[res_i-1]);
        
        if(r<q && r<p) --res_i;
        else if(q<r && q<p) ++res_i;

        int res_j = binary_search(vec3, tstamp);

        p = dabs(tstamp-vec3[res_j]);
        q = dabs(tstamp-vec3[res_j+1]); 
        r = dabs(tstamp-vec3[res_j-1]);
        
        if(r<q && r<p) --res_j;
        else if(q<r && q<p) ++res_j;

        double first = tstamp-vec2[res_i]; 
        double second = tstamp-vec3[res_j]; 
        double third = vec2[res_i] - vec3[res_j]; 
        double fourth = std::min(std::min(first, second), third);

        coincidences.push_back({tstamp, vec2[res_i], vec3[res_j], first, second, third, fourth});
    
    {"UNIX"});
    
    std::sort(coincidences.begin(), coincidences.end(),
        [](const vector<double>& A, const vector<double>& B){
            return A[6] < B[6];
    });
    
        std::set<double> cache;


    for(auto pair : coincidences){
        
        if(cache.find(pair[1]) == cache.end() && cache.find(pair[2]) == cache.end())    {
            std::cout << "Coincidence found!\n";
            cache.insert(pair[1]); cache.insert(pair[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: CERN's ROOT framework can be found at https://root.cern.ch

Comment: Are these 2 functions members of a class, and if so could you please include the rest of the class. Can you please provide a link to the CERN's ROOT data analysis framework.

Comment: @pacmaninbw They are not. I've added a link to ROOT (root.cern.ch). Note that the only lines using ROOT are the first 6 of `binary()`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I should add that, perhaps it's a bit confusing that this does not have, for instance, an `int main()` function. This is running in the ROOT intepereter which, while *almost* perfectly ISO compliant, has a couple small quirks, such as having the main function be a void with the name being the same as the filename. Here, `void binary()` is the equivalent of `int main()`.

Comment: does it have extra brace at `statn1.Foreach([&](double tstamp){},` and it should be lambda with all tabbed code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Undefined behavior

There's UB in case when empty vector passed to the `binary_search`.

```cpp
unsigned int mid;
```

it is uninitialised and will pop whatever compiler think he want in release mode. To solve this issue it is require initialise value with some error value (usually it is `~0` but you can choose your own), or use `std::optional` (c++17) and handle error case in lambda.
probably it is not an issue if vectors guaranteed to be non-empty and there's at least one proper value inside them.

#### mix of signed and unsigned types

Return type of `binary_search` is `int`, but branches can be `unsigned int`.
As it is actually return position in vector best way to use special unsigned integral type macro `size_t` meant to be used like this. So final check will be like.

```cpp
...
constexpr size_t ERR = ~0;
siz_t res_i = binary_search(vec2, tstamp);
if (ERR == res_i) return; // early exit from lambda
...
```

But that kind of handling raise question about how to handle `res_i--` if binary search return position 0. It probably will return INT_MAX for according integral type, but that kind of subtraction is implementation defined behavior so result defined by compiler.

#### potential out of bounds

if binary search return `0` position access to `-1` will crash your program.

```
double r = dabs(tstamp-vec2[res_i-1]);
```

tightly related to previous issues.
probably it is not an issue if found position never meant to be 0

#### unnecessary variable reusing

If your program don't meant to be run on some embed device this kind of optimization basically do nothing - compilers usually smart enough to get rid of it by themselves. Probably good idea create some small function and `p`,`q`,`r` manipulations in it. Also it will prevent chance to make copy-paste errors

```
size_t someRoutine(double tstamp, const auto& vec, size_t res) {
  double p = dabs(tstamp-vec[res]); 
  double q = dabs(tstamp-vec[res+1]); 
  double r = dabs(tstamp-vec[res-1]);
        
  if(r<q && r<p) return res-1;
  if(q<r && q<p) return res+1;
  return res;
}
//...
res_i = someRoutine(tstamp, vec2, res_i);
res_j = someRoutine(tstamp, vec3, res_j);
```

#### structs clearer than vector

it is good idea to create a struct instead of using a vector - less memory print, clearer usage.

```cpp
struct SomData{
  double tstamp, vec2,vec3, first, second, third, fourth;
};
//...
coincidences.push_back({tstamp, vec2[res_i], vec3[res_j], first, second, third, fourth});
// OR
// coincidences.emplace_back(tstamp, vec2[res_i], vec3[res_j], first, second, third, fourth); // construct struct in-place, 
//...
std::sort(coincidences.begin(), coincidences.end(),
   [](const SomData& A, const SomData>& B){
            return A.fourth < B.fourth;
});
///...
cache.insert(pair.vec2);cache.insert(pair.vec3);
```

#### no need to use find if you don't need an iterator

maps ands sets have convenient method `count` which represents amount of items found by the key. You just need to check whether its zero or one

```cpp
if(cache.count(pair.vec2) == 0 && cache.count(pair.vec3) == 0) {
  std::cout << "Coincidence found!\n";
  cache.insert(pair.vec2);
  cache.insert(pair.vec3);
}
```

#### cycle copy elements

probably just missed `&`

```cpp
for(const auto& pair : coincidences){
```